# Link inside modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal and a link inside that modal. Is it possible to not load the target of the link in the modal ? Because that's what happens now when I click on the link.

I want to load the target in the browser, like a normal link. I tried adding data-dismiss="modal" both with and without the href and it won't dismiss the modal.

Tried some onclick javascript to redirect but somehow it loaded the content in the modal, as usual:

> onclick="window.location.href='the_link_to_go_to.html';"

Comment: why don't you add an IFRAME inside the modal itself and open next link within it?

Comment: @DeepakYadav — It sounds like the OP is … and that is the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably the "modal" is an iframe.

To break out of a frame and open a document in the top level, use the target attribute.

```
<a href="http://example.com" target="_top">...</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try

```
onclick="window.open(yourLinkHere)"

//or

<a href="yourLinkHere" target="_blank">go to my link</a>
```

Comment: Because that would open a new window, and that isn't the goal.